# ng serve not serving images but npm start works fine

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am learning angular 6. 
When I run my project with the "ng serve" angular command, I cannot see any pictures. Instead I have the message:

> GET http://localhost:4200/src/assets/header.jpg 404 (Not Found) platform-browser.js: 1087

However, when I run the project with the "npm start" command, it works correctly.

Why ng serve does not work?

**SOLVED**

Ater remove /src/ from image links project works properly.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the `src` value of this `img` element?

Comment: In this case: <img src="/src/assets/header.jpg" alt="" />. Applying ./src/ or src/ does not help.

Comment: I think that `/src/` is superficial. Can you try removing it?

Comment: <img [src]=“” /> is the notation you want

Comment: @enterman can you post your package.json content here ?

Comment: Try  `<img src="/assets/header.jpg" />`

Comment: `src` is the root, the fact that the CLI is teeling you that it start looking **outside** the src is the problem. You need to remove one '../', just that.

Answer (score 0):

`npm start` run `ng serve` as defined in the `package.json`.
Are you sure you have well defined the img src ?

For instance :

`<img src="../../../assets/images/logo.png">`